# Running a task forever in php

Tags: php

I have a web application that must check something in a special period of time. It can be checked in each 5 minutes. But the ideal is running almost forever.

What I'm going to do, is connecting to a social network api, and update something in my database. The first approach is setting a `cron jobs`.

But I can run the script from command line **forever**:

```
while (true) {
    // my code here
}
```

So, which one is better for my case? Does second one affect to apache's requests? Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: What you are looking for is a daemon. Some process that is controlled by the system. Such daemon can be implemented in any language you like, but php is not exactly a language well suited for such task, its strong points lie else where. Nevertheless this _is_ possible, just make sure that you allow that process to sleep inbetween, otherwise it will eat 100% of your CPU resources.

Comment: If you dont need something to run multiple times **within a minute** then you dont need a daemon.

Comment: What about while ture with sleep

Comment: @arkascha I can understand what you tell about language. But the library I used is not implemented in other languages like `nodejs`. And there is a huge library to connecting to telegram core api. So, what is your final suggestion?

Comment: @user1844933 What is the result of `sleep()` for this case? Just for cpu usage?

Comment: Sleep alows the CPU to attend to other tasks and return after a specified amount of time.

Comment: Check out: https://gist.github.com/lcherone/28b92af0f06c1224b30fe734a0d51877

Comment: `nodejs` is not a language, it is a server or maybe a platform. Languages would be something like c, c++, java, javascript. If I get you right, then you want to use some library implemented in php? If so then certainly using that language does make sense, though there are alternatives to that.

Comment: You implement a php script which processes the required task and start that by a crontab entry. That is easiest. An alternative would be to have the script started by a daemon control script (you can take examples from existing daemons on your system), but that means the php script itself will need to implement a loop as already discussed _and_ you need to implement some form of "watch dog" logic that takes care to restart your script if it fails or is killed.

Comment: @arkascha the cron does "watchdog" `while sleep 1; do ... ; done` if it fails it starts again. - I'm not keen on forever daemons as memory leaks are more apparent, least this way it clears every min.

Comment: The main thing about using `cron` is that if the server restarts - so will the jobs.  If you run it from the console, you would have to log back in and run the script again.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone No! Combining `cron` with an endless loop will result in the system getting flooded with processes!

Comment: @NigelRen No, you can use a daemon control script for that just as with any other daemon. `cron` itself (the cron daemon) for example demonstrates that.

Comment: Daemon scripts can be run all over the place.  BUT will your hosting company let you set up daemon processes?  `cron` jobs on the other hand are supported by most (if not all) hosting companies.

Comment: @arkascha not if you use a pid file, lol did you look at my gist? Ive used similar code across 30+ servers, inc windows to sync stats and build configurations, never had an issue..

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Sure, possible, but then you implement the protection, it has nothing to do with cron. Cron can only start a process.

Comment: @arkascha yeah your right cron is cron, it does nothing more than fire a script. Though you need to add logic to code for it to do anything. Even upstart/systemd needs logic to run.

Comment: Would anyone summarize the discussion as an answer please? possible ways, with pros and cons of each way? Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

If you can predict more than one cron job to be executed you can try https://github.com/lavary/crunz (or any other library like this) where you can config jobs scheduler in PHP. Regardless, I would not use PHP app as a daemon, running it every x min/hours is only way for me. If this is not acceptable probably choosing different lang is an answer ;).

Answer (score 0):

Go with the `cron jobs`.

The second one will call the task immediately & infinitely. And also you have to keep a page open in a browser or have to make a HTTP request to that page.

Comment: No, second one does not require too keep any browser page open. I can run it by console.

Comment: Then its fine. But the cron jobs way is better & effective one.

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible to reach the 5 minute call via `AJAX`?

Comment: You can use interval function by setting the duration to 5 minutes.
Example: setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 5 * 60 *1000);